# Why isn't the Visualizing Turtlebot Kinect data tutorial working?

Tags: ros, kinect, rviz, turtlebot, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use the Visualizing Turtlebot Kinect data tutorial. I run the command on the turtlebot, and start rviz on my laptop. I then add a camera, and set a topic without a problem. Finally I don't get any visualization and rviz says it is getting input.

**Rviz:**
rosrun rviz rviz -d `rospack find turtlebot_navigation`/nav_rviz.vcg

```
10. Camera (Camera) CameraInfo  No CameraInfo received on [/camera_info].
Topic may not exist. Image  No image
received Image Topic 
/camera/rgb/image_color
```

**Turtlebot:**

```
turtlebot@turtlebot-0169:~$ roslaunch turtlebot_bringup kinect.launch
... logging to /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/4d75f176-e274-11e0-90a4-485d607558c5/roslaunch-turtlebot-0169-24706.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://turtlebot-0169:46881/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /kinect_laser/max_height
 * /openni_camera/depth_rgb_rotation
 * /rosdistro
 * /openni_camera/image_mode
 * /openni_camera/image_time_offset
 * /openni_camera/projector_depth_baseline
 * /kinect_laser_narrow/output_frame_id
 * /openni_camera/depth_mode
 * /kinect_laser_narrow/max_height
 * /openni_camera/depth_frame_id
 * /openni_camera/depth_time_offset
 * /kinect_laser/output_frame_id
 * /rosversion
 * /openni_camera/depth_registration
 * /openni_camera/debayering
 * /openni_camera/depth_rgb_translation
 * /kinect_laser/min_height
 * /pointcloud_throttle/max_rate
 * /openni_camera/shift_offset
 * /kinect_laser_narrow/min_height
 * /openni_camera/rgb_frame_id

NODES
  /
    kinect_breaker_enabler (turtlebot_node/kinect_breaker_enabler.py)
    openni_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    openni_camera (nodelet/nodelet)
    pointcloud_throttle (nodelet/nodelet)
    kinect_laser (nodelet/nodelet)
    kinect_laser_narrow (nodelet/nodelet)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[kinect_breaker_enabler-1]: started with pid [24728]
process[openni_manager-2]: started with pid [24729]
process[openni_camera-3]: started with pid [24730]
process[pointcloud_throttle-4]: started with pid [24731]
process[kinect_laser-5]: started with pid [24732]
process[kinect_laser_narrow-6]: started with pid [24745]
[ INFO] [1316405792.993553544]: [/openni_camera] Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1316405792.994095757]: [/openni_camera] 1. device on bus 001:12 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'A00365918487050A'
[ WARN] [1316405792.997785161]: [/openni_camera] device_id is not set! Using first device.
[ INFO] [1316405793.041290217]: [/openni_camera] Opened 'Xbox NUI Camera' on bus 1:12 with serial number 'A00365918487050A'
[ INFO] [1316405793.093197084]: rgb_frame_id = 'kinect_rgb_optical_frame' 
[ INFO] [1316405793.100211019]: depth_frame_id = 'kinect_depth_optical_frame' 
[kinect_breaker_enabler-1] process has finished cleanly.
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/4d75f176-e274-11e0-90a4-485d607558c5/kinect_breaker_enabler-1*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11245/why-isn%27t-the-visualizing-turtlebot-kinect-data-tutorial-working?/) by [edgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/258/edgan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2011-09-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-09-18**:
your console output looks correct/ Can you rostopic hz /camera/rgb/image_color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wasn't setting ROS_HOSTNAME on the turtlebot. So it was defaulting to the hostname, like ROS_HOSTNAME=turtlebot-0169. My laptop couldn't resolve turtlebot-0169, and so it couldn't pull the data for rviz.

---

Originally posted by [edgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/258/edgan/) with karma: 66 on 2011-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1